# vector.push_back() produces deleted function error when pushing a thread (during compilation)

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I do not understand why, but `vector<thread>.push_back()` produces an error.
I have tried replacing the error-producing line with `.emplace_back()`, but I still get this error.

Overall, my code is attempting to display what numbers are prime based on the input. I know for sure, and have already tested, that the splitString() and isPrime() functions work perfectly, just that my implementation into main() is improper and produces an error when compiling.

Here is my code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int number) {
    int scan = number - 1;
    while(scan > 1){
        if(number % scan == 0){
            return false;
        }
        scan = scan - 1;
    }
    return true;
}
vector<string> splitString(string String, string seperator){
    vector<string> result;
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    while((pos = String.find(seperator)) != string::npos){
        token = String.substr(0, pos);
        result.push_back(token);
        String.erase(0, pos + seperator.length());
    }
    result.push_back(String);
    return result;
}
string getPrimes(string param){
    vector<string> splitstring = splitString(param, ",");
    string outstring = "";
    int currentScan = stoi(splitstring[0]);
    int higher = stoi(splitstring[1]);
    while(currentScan <= higher){
        bool res = isPrime(currentScan);
        if(res == true){
            outstring = outstring + to_string(currentScan) + ",";
            cout << to_string(currentScan) + ",";
        }
        currentScan = currentScan + 1;
    }
    return outstring;
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int initVal = atoi(argv[0]);
    int threadLength = atoi(argv[1]);
    int threadCount = atoi(argv[2]);
    vector<thread> threads;
    int threadPart = 1;
    while(threadPart <= threadCount){
        int threadStart = (threadPart * threadLength) + initVal;
        int threadEnd = threadStart + threadLength;
        string inp = to_string(threadStart) + "," + to_string(threadEnd);
        thread th(getPrimes, inp);
        threads.push_back(th);
        threadPart = threadPart + 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++){
        threads[i].join();
    }
}
```

Here is the produced error;

```
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/string:41,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from primes.cpp:1:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::thread; _Args = {std::thread&}; _Tp = std::thread]':
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from 'static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::thread; _Args = {std::thread&}; _Tp = std::thread; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::thread>]'
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc:103:30:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::thread&}; _Tp = std::thread; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>]'
primes.cpp:55:32:   required from here
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: use of deleted function 'std::thread::thread(std::thread&)'
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from primes.cpp:4:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/thread:109:5: note: declared here
     thread(thread&) = delete;
     ^~~~~~
```

I am new to C++ and C in general. Why does this error happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems because copying threads isn't allowed.

You can use `threads.push_back(std::move(th));` instead of `threads.push_back(th);`.

Another choice is using

```
threads.push_back(thread(getPrimes, inp));
```

instead of

```
thread th(getPrimes, inp);
threads.push_back(th);
```

Comment: I suppose also `threads.emplace_back(getPrimes, inp)`?